# Android where to create ScheduledThreadPool and what happens if not shutdown?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a `ScheduledThreadPool` to run some method calls periodically.
For an example I want to save everything to the DB every 10 seconds...
So I got:

```
public class Scheduler{
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

public Scheduler(){
    foo = Foo.getInstance();

    saveValues();
}

private void saveValues(){
    ScheduledFuture saveValues = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "in save values");

                    foo.save();
                }
            }, 2000, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
}
```

but the problem is it runs once and never again. 
I read in one tutorial that it is important to shut down the `Executer` cause it might run on forever otherwise so I expected I did not need to take care of it's lifecycle except for creating it and shutting it down at one point.

`Foo` is an Api which is a singleton. It gets called by the `activity` and calls `Scheduler`. I was also wondering if it should extend Application, but did not find it necessary yet.

Where in my app do I need to call it, is it ok in the Scheduler class or not? Does Scheduler need to be a Runnable? And where exactly do I shut down the Executer?

Thanks in advance

ps: if you think that an Executer is not the right way to do it, let me know. I looked through many threads and pages and did not find a perfect answer so the Executer seemed alright.

Comment: try recursion with 10second time out. `Thread.sleep(10000)` or something like that. It is not necessary to use `scheduledExecutorService`. Also make sure you do not start that in the UI thread. Try `class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { }` then `new RetreivePicture().execute();`

Comment: I need a couple of operations to be scheduled so just a simple thread isn't really doing it. Back to the main question: how, when, where do I use the Executer? :D

Comment: Does `foo.save()` ever return?

Comment: should :D 
just saving to the Db, then returning.

Comment: but it seems you might be right. But it still leaves my questions open about the whole scheduledThreadPool construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it be bound to just one Activity? of you need the functionality across your application even if the activity is destroyed?

I made such functionality extending Service. Here is the code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    static final public String SERVICE_RESULT = "com.my.app.MyService.SMS_UPDATED";
    static final public String SERVICE_MESSAGE = "SMS updated";

    int SECONDS = 10;

    LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
                scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                      // do some processing... and then

                      sendResult(SERVICE_MESSAGE);

                    }
                }, SECONDS, SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

       // if you need any initialization...
    }


    public void sendResult(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SERVICE_RESULT);
        if (message != null)
            intent.putExtra(SERVICE_RESULT, message);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

So, I use an intent to communicate the result of the processing back to my app. By using the `scheduleAtFixedRate` I am able to run the task every 10 seconds, you should modify it to your needs. Then, notice the Service.START_STICKY;    it defines if the service should be restarted or not.

The code you posted seems to be correct, but, if it's within an activiy and you need it in others.. maybe it's being destroyed.

Comment: hey, looks quite good, I will try it out.
The main problem as I figured was in my case what Fildor pointed out, that the method never returned but you answered some of the other questions, thanks.

Comment: This can be used very widely, very useful Thank! +1